# re formatting css - collapse redundant paths?

Tags: html, css

my stylesheets tend to have a *lot* of redundancy.  for example,

```
/* example one: different attributes */
div#main_work > div.main_work table.data td span.rating,
div#main_work > div.main_work table.data td span.follow 
   { white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: center; }

/* example two: same upstream, different downstream */
div#main_work > div.main_work > form table,
div#main_work > div.main_work > table,
div#main_work > div.main_work div table
   { width: 100%; margin: 0px;  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

is there a syntactically correct way to collapse this?

Comment: Kind of redundant question. It's like saying you've got a bag of marbles and asking the probability of picking a green one, how are we to know unless we know what colour / how many marbles you have? CSS can only be simplified on a case-by-case basis depending on your HTML, which makes the question excessively localised, or in this case impossible without seeing your HTML. That said it seems elclanrs has given the most logical simplification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's just how it is. You could alleviate some troubles by being less specific about things, especially in ID selectors:

```css
/* example one: different attributes */
#main_work > .main_work .data .rating,
#main_work > .main_work .data .follow 
   { white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: center; }

/* example two: same upstream, different downstream */
#main_work > .main_work > form table,
#main_work > .main_work > table,
#main_work > .main_work div table
   { width: 100%; margin: 0px;  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

And you can probably reduce this further. Try to be concise and obvious about the intent. As another alternative, you might try [LESS stylesheets](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: thanks for your reply.  as you might imagine, have gotten severely bit by underspecifying -don't want to go there again - way too long to dig out from that mess.  yes, `less` is a valid option for some.

Comment: @ccyoung: Overspecifying is *much* worse. Trust me and just simplify your expressions. If you won't do that, the least you can do is remove `div` from `div#main_work`. It's completely redundant and hinders performance.

Comment: agree on removing `div` from `div#main` - that was overboard for sure.  but I am interested in why you content over-specifying is _much worse_.  from my perspective, paying attention to over-specifying falls in the class of premature optimization.

Comment: You should not run into under-specifying if you think about your selectors first.

Comment: If you're still unsure, just run this test http://jsperf.com/over-specifying-test. It's testing over-specifying in jQuery, but expect similar results in css.

Comment: thanks for the link!  but I would still like to learn why you feel so strongly about over-specifying.  for me it has saved tons of time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know your html code, but you can probably get rid of a few things and target the actual elements needed and avoid over-specification. Just an example, fit to your needs, but you get the idea:

```
/* example one: different attributes */
.main_work .rating,
.main_work .follow 
   { white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: center; }

/* example two: same upstream, different downstream */
.main_work table,
.main_work form table,
.main_work div table
   { width: 100%; margin: 0px;  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: thanks, but from my perspective over-specification is a venal sin of adding unnecessary bytes to the tubes, whereas under-specification is a mortal sin that dooms one to the purgatory of debugging css for two or three lifetimes.  (apologies to good Catholics)